# SetWindowDisplayAffinity not works in MFC windows

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, screenshot

I have 1 **Picture Control** and want to make it **not screen record-able**.
In .Net, I have been using [`SetWindowDisplayAffinity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity):

```cs
WDA_MONTOR = 1;
SetWindowDisplayAffinity(this.Handle, WDA_MONTOR);
```

Now I have moved to **MFC** for native performance.
I am using this following code which don't prevent **screenshots**:

```cpp
HWND Handle = this->GetDlgItem(IDC_SCREEN)->m_hWnd;
SetWindowDisplayAffinity(Handle, WDA_MONITOR);
```

Complete example:

```
if(SetWindowDisplayAffinity(hWnd, WDA_MONITOR)==false)
{
    wchar_t buf[256];
    FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        buf, (sizeof(buf) / sizeof(wchar_t)), NULL);
    AfxMessageBox(buf);
}
```

`GetLastError` says "parameter is incorrect".

Comment: I am not familiar with the API but shouldn't the flag be `WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE `?  And according to the docs the return value is `BOOL` and if `FALSE` you can make use of `GetLastError` to investigate.

Comment: WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE introduced in windows 10. GetLastError says `parameter is incorrect`. See code https://rentry.co/agvyh

Comment: I updated your question with this info as it helps. But, it is beyond my knowledge so maybe someone else can help.

Comment: The .NET version was passing the form's window handle (a top-level window), but your MFC version is passing a control's window handle (a child window). Use the top-level window.

Comment: @RaymondChen big fan of u. I read your articles. Pls can you suggest me any top-level window like panel, layout etc ?

Comment: You should pick the top-level window you want to protect.

Comment: @RaymondChen I got it working with your help :`SetWindowDisplayAffinity(this->m_hWnd , WDA_MONITOR)`. Answer & I will tick.Thanks

Comment: Go ahead and post an answer and accept it.

Comment: Thanks. Getting guidance from you was my honour. You are very respectable for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to **[Raymond chen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65091056/setwindowdisplayaffinity-not-works-in-mfc-windows?noredirect=1#comment115082811_65091056)**:

> The .NET version was passing the form's window handle (a top-level window), but your MFC version is passing a control's window handle (a child window). Use the top-level window.

That's mean I would have to use **Form** handle instead of **PictureBox** handle.
So change

```cpp
HWND Handle = this->GetDlgItem(IDC_SCREEN)->m_hWnd; //PictureBox handle
SetWindowDisplayAffinity(Handle, WDA_MONITOR);
```

to

```cpp
HWND Handle = this->m_hWnd;      //form handle
SetWindowDisplayAffinity(Handle, WDA_MONITOR);
```

Reason: **Form** window is **parent** and **top-level** window.