# Problem with using SetWindowDisplayAffinity in Delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi, screenshot

I received various feedback and assistance in my previous question ([prevents screenshots or screen capturing in delphi (alexandria)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78000140/)), and after some searching and research, I came across the following source code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls, Vcl.Menus, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.FileCtrl, 
  System.IOUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, Forms, Math, ShellAPI, Vcl.Imaging.jpeg, 
  Winapi.TlHelp32, PsAPI, System.StrUtils;


type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;


var
  Form1: TForm1;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses Unit2;

function SetWindowDisplayAffinity(hWnd: HWND; dwAffinity: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall; external 'user32.dll' name 'SetWindowDisplayAffinity';
function ShowWindow(hWnd: HWND; nCmdShow: Integer): BOOL; stdcall; external 'user32.dll' name 'ShowWindow';


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
 Handle: Winapi.Windows.HWND;
begin
  // Get the handle of the main form window
  Handle := Self.Handle;

  // Set the display affinity of the window to monitor
  SetWindowDisplayAffinity(Handle, WDA_MONITOR);

  // Call SetWindowDisplayAffinity
  if not SetWindowDisplayAffinity(Handle, WDA_MONITOR) then
  begin
    ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
  end else
  begin
    ShowMessage('OK');
  end;


  // Show the window
  ShowWindow(Handle, SW_NORMAL);
end;
```

However, I still don't have the ability to replace the black screen or blank page with my software page, or prevent capturing my software page.

Is there an issue with my source code?

I do not intend to write security software, so please do not give repetitive answers like this method is not effective, outdated, not practical, etc. I want to learn the method and process, and surely anyone with minimal technology knowledge knows that it is possible to capture or record the screen using a digital camera or mobile camera, and these methods cannot be prevented. Or by other methods, such as reverse engineering, etc., these limitations can be bypassed.

My goal is only to learn, and I do not intend to write flawless software!

These answers were very helpful, but I still couldn't succeed in using this method in Delphi 11 Alexandria: *"I was not successful in installing and running the DirectX SDK method in Delphi 11 Alexandria, so I preferred to use the SetWindowDisplayAffinity method instead. (If this method is compatible with most Windows systems, especially Windows 7 to 11, it is sufficient for me.)"*

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22218857/4299358

[How does Office 2013 implement black windows for IRM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268004/)

Comment: "_I came across the following source codes_" - then why not linking where you got it from? `Handle := Self.Handle` is **very** ridiculous. Also the example is not reduced to the minimum - out of the 23 units only one is relevant! How do you conclude "_I still don't have the ability_" and why are you calling `SetWindowDisplayAffinity()` twice?

Comment: @AmigoJack, I deleted the line below, but it still doesn't work. Which part of the code might be causing the issue?
`// Set the display affinity of the window to monitor
  SetWindowDisplayAffinity(Handle, WDA_MONITOR);`
I have written the source code in my question based on the source code available at [C++ Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65091056/setwindowdisplayaffinity-not-works-in-mfc-windows) and then converted it to Delphi. (Of course, I had to ask for help from AI which only made my problems worse!)

Comment: Don't use AI. It's like cheating in school: it may appear like a great idea at the time, but it will hurt you in the long run.

Comment: I'm curious: Did you read the description of the "affinity" tag when you added it to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is strange in a number of ways:

1. Why do you call [`SetWindowDisplayAffinity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity) two times (one time without error checking and one time with error checking)? Surely one time is enough, no?
2. Why do you call `ShowWindow` in the `OnCreate` handler? And why do you feel the need to declare this function yourself, when in fact it is a standard Windows API function found in `Windows.pas`?
3. Why do you include a huge number of units in your example? (It is almost like you *want* to confuse us -- and yourself -- by creating red herrings!)

I just now created a new VCL application in Delphi 12 with the following `OnClick` handler:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not SetWindowDisplayAffinity(Handle, WDA_MONITOR) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

I also added a button to the form (just to see how child windows appear in screenshots) and some GDI drawing on the form itself:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
  Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  Canvas.Pen.Width := 4;
  Canvas.Ellipse(ClientRect)
end;
```

Now, I run the application and (immediately) create a screenshot of it and its neighbourhood:

[image: Screenshot of running app in front of its source code in the RAD Studio IDE. You can see a red circle and a button in the form.]

Then I click the client area of the form (NOT the button) and try to capture it in a screenshot again:

[image: Screenshot of running app in front of its source code in the RAD Studio IDE. The entire app window is black.]

By moving the call to `SetWindowDisplayAffinity` to the form's `OnCreate` handler, it will be "uncapturable" from the beginning. (Actually, `CreateWnd` is probably a better place.)

So regarding the issue of "The problem with using SetWindowDisplayAffinity in the Delphi", I'd say the problem doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you so much for both the suggestion you provided and the response you gave. I completely agree with your suggestion; it was the first time I had to use ai, and I deeply regret that choice. I am totally bewildered by your response!! I created a new project without adding any other code (even without adding any `"uses"` statements), and simply added the code snippet you provided to the `FormCreate` event, and everything worked perfectly! So, it seems that I really didn't need to use any library files or other files, right?

Comment: Is the possibility of the screen turning black achievable across all Windows versions? Does this feature apply to the entire project, or do I need to call this code separately for each form or section?

Comment: @John: (2) The [`SetWindowDisplayAffinity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity) function takes a window handle (HWND) as argument, and "Specifies where the content of the window can be displayed." So it only affects the window with the HWND you pass to it. In the example above, this is the `Self` window. If you have 10 top-level windows in your app, you need to call `SetWindowDisplayAffinity` ten times or put the call in a base class. (1) Again according to the docs, the function is available on Windows 7 and later, BUT ...

Comment: (cont.) "it works only when the Desktop Window Manager(DWM) is composing the desktop." In addition, the documentation says, "It is important to note that unlike a security feature or an implementation of Digital Rights Management (DRM), there is no guarantee that using SetWindowDisplayAffinity and GetWindowDisplayAffinity, and other necessary functions such as DwmIsCompositionEnabled, will strictly protect windowed content, for example where someone takes a photograph of the screen."

Comment: So if you are on Windows 7 and disable Aero (so you get the Windows 9x look), it won't work.

Comment: But this is indeed a great way to make it very difficult to accidentally capture sensitive information on any reasonably modern Windows PC. It will almost never fail. (I wonder if it works in remote sessions. That may be a major exception. Virtual machines is an even bigger issue, I think. Now we are effectively at the "point camera to monitor" level.)

Comment: Yes, you don't need the DwmApi unit; the `SetWindowDisplayAffinity` function is also present in the standard Windows.pas unit. My bad.

Comment: Thank you again for sharing your knowledge with others and providing detailed explanations. What is the difference between `SetWindowDisplayAffinity`, `GetWindowDisplayAffinity`, and other essential functions like `DwmIsCompositionEnabled`, and what are their functions? Are these functions separate from each other but with similar functionality? Can these functions be used together as complements to strengthen a program? Are there other functions or commands that have similar functionality to `SetWindowDisplayAffinity`? I would appreciate it if you could provide some information on this.

Comment: When I tested my virtual machine on Windows 7, I received the following error:
`---------------------------
Project1
---------------------------
System Error. Code: 8.

Not enough storage is available to process this command.
---------------------------
OK
---------------------------
`
Even though the physical memory is at 25% and there is 1 gigabyte of free hard drive space.

Comment: You mean that you get that exception when you call `SetWindowDisplayAffinity` running in the remote Windows 7 machine? If so, this is likely because DWM (and thus Aero) is not enabled, as I noted above.

Comment: The SetWindowDisplayAffinity or DwmIsCompositionEnabled or... functions can prevent screen capturing by third-party software like Camtasia? Because I tested with a software, the screen was captured normally and without any problems (the screen was not black and was normal).

Comment: Yes in VM and win7-64bit but in win7 without VM is ok

Comment: @John: I don't know how these third-party apps work. I tested on Win 11 with Windows's own screen grabbing tool, Alt+Print Screen, Print Screen, and ShareX (third-party application). In all cases, I got a black window. But if there are 17 third-party screen grabbing apps available today on the market, you need to test each one of them separately. They may be using different techniques and some may go to extreme lengths to avoid any protection. This is why this entire API is supposed only to make "accidental capture of sensitive information less likely". This is not a security feature.

Comment: After all, if you can see the window on the monitor, you can simply take a photo of the monitor, or connect the HDMI/DP/VGA/DVI cable to a special "screen recording device" (instead of a monitor), or some device driver on the system may read the output signal directly from the graphics card. There are no guarantees, but you really need to make an effort to bypass this "protection" (unless DWM is disabled -- and anyone can very easily disable DWM in Windows 7, for instance).

Comment: (1) - 
Thank you.
I'm sorry if I have asked too many questions. If you do not wish to answer these questions, please ignore them because I have reached the answer I was looking for with your help. I just want to learn more things.
Is it only possible to disable `DWM (and thus Aero)` in Windows 7? 
Can it be determined whether the current windows have this capability or not, or if it is enabled or disabled? (I mean through coding)

Comment: (2) - Is it possible to determine if `SetWindowDisplayAffinity` has been executed correctly and blackened the screen or not? I don't mean error or other issues, but I mean being able to detect whether `SetWindowDisplayAffinity` has been applied correctly through the codes.

Is the function `DwmIsCompositionEnabled` similar to `SetWindowDisplayAffinity` or does it have a different function? Because most similar topics have discussed these two or three functions (`GetWindowDisplayAffinity`) together.

Comment: @John: Both your questions can be answered by reading the documentation for [`SetWindowDisplayAffinity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity) and [`DwmIsCompositionEnabled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmiscompositionenabled). All functions in Microsoft Windows are well documented, and developers are always supposed to read the docs for any new function they want to use. The documentation should explain all questions the developer may have.

Comment: @John: First, read the documentation that you've been provided links for multiple times. Second, if you have additional questions, use the *Ask Question* button in the upper right corner of this page and ask them there. Comments are to be used for **brief followup questions or comments**, not long discussions and many additional questions.